# You must provide a value expression following the '-Like' operator

Tags: python, powershell

I want to enable IIS by Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature in windows 8,so I write a python program,its code is:

```
os.system('powershell -Command "%s"' % r'Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $(Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where { $_.FeatureName -Like "IIS-*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FeatureName)')
```

when I run the program, it shows that this:

```
PS C:\Python27> ./python fr.py
At line:1 char:119
+ ... WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where { $_.FeatureName -Like IIS-*}  ...
+                                                                  ~
You must provide a value expression following the '-Like' operator.
At line:1 char:120
+ ... sOptionalFeature -Online | Where { $_.FeatureName -Like IIS-*} | Sele ...
+                                                          ~~~~~
Unexpected token 'IIS-*' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [],ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

can you help with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the double quotes via backslash. `... Where { $_.FeatureName -Like \"IIS-*\"}  ...`

The main trouble is that `os.system()` invokes a command-line parsing of full parameter string, which eats up double quotes as part of parsing sequential arguments. Backslash prevents "overparsing" double quotes, passing them to Powershell. An example:

```
>>> os.system('powershell -command "%s"' % r'get-process | where {$_.name -like \"powershell*\"}')

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    286      24    57948      54196   606     0,51   5336 powershell
    501      32    46540      58164   239     7,58   5456 powershell
```

Comment: thanks, I have modified it. but it shows another error: 

Get-WindowsOptionalFeature : An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
At line:1 char:54
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $(Get-
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'FeatureName'. The argument is null or empty.
Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: This means `Get-WindowsFeature` returned null. Check if IIS as a feature is available on the remote machine.